# Django Databases: Many to Many of a foregin key in a HASHTAG - FOLLOWER relation

Tags: django, database

Let's think I build Instagram platform.

**I need to lookup fast

I have 2 models:

```
class Follower():
   hastags = ???
```

```
class Hashtag():
    name = char...
```

ABILITY:

To be able to fetch -**all** specific follower- hashtags.

And reverse: fetch -**all** Followers- of a specific hastags.

---

NOTES:

A Follower don't have to have an hashtag.

An Hashtag exist only once a follower is adding it.

I think I can put a foreginKey on Hashtag instead of Follower but this seems to be messy since I mostly deal with the followers not the hashtags.
I know I can add a funtion to add hashtag to follower in the follower model.

So best option is to use ManyToMany from Followers to Hashtags ? correct me if I am wrong ?

---

EXAMPLE:

Follower1 uses Hashtags: Tag1, Tag2

Follower2 uses Hashtags: Tag2, Tag3

Comment: Can one hashtag be followed by multiple followers?

Comment: Yes 1 hashtag can be used(they use it not follow it) in many followers.
added exampke

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you'd use a many-to-many field.

```
class Follower(models.Model):
   followed_hashtags = models.ManyToManyField('Hashtag', related_name='followers')
```

To get all of the hashtags followed by someone, you can use the forward descriptor

```
hashtags = follower.followed_hashtags.all()
```

To get all of the followers for a hashtag, you can use the reverse descriptor

```
cat_hashtag = Hashtag.objects.get(name='cat')
cat_followers = cat_hashtag.followers.all()
```

You can also use the implicitly generated `through` table/model for even more interesting lookups, such as summaries of follow counts:

```
HashtagFollows = Follower.followed_hashtags.through
counts = HashtagFollows.objects.all().values('hashtag__name').annotate(count=Count())
```

This implicit table can also be used for lookups if you only have e.g. a follower ID:

```
follower_8s_hashtag_names = HashtagFollows.objects.filter(follower_id=8).values_list('hashtag__name')
```

And, if you need to e.g. store when a given Follower started following a hashtag, see [extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) (which then replaces the implicit through table).

Comment: What can he do to insure the best performance ? should he add db_index=True?

Comment: The underlying foreign key fields in the through table are already indexed (since they're foreign keys).

Comment: What will happen if we add the same Hashtag to the same Follower 2 times ? will it do nothing ?

Comment: Unless you customize the through table, it will have an `unique_together` constraint, so you can't add a hashtag twice.